# Django whitenoise versioning not working

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, waitress

I am using whitenoise with waitress to serve my static files, but I could not get it to use the versioned static file. For example, if I have a foo.js, after I run collectstatic, whitenoise creates the following files in my static folder:

```
foo.js
foo.js.gz
foo.10a400e06df8.js
foo.10a400e06df8.js.gz where 10a400e06df8 is the unique version code that whitenoise generated for me.
```

Here is my wsgi.py file:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# This is the default application
application = get_wsgi_application()

def white():
    # This is an alternative WSGI app that wraps static content
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
    white = get_wsgi_application()
    white = DjangoWhiteNoise(white)
    return white
```

Here is how I include the foo.js in my template:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
...
<script src="{% static "foo.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I run my waitress server as follows:

waitress-serve --port=8080 --call myapp.wsgi:white

When I load my page, I am expecting I would see this in my browser

```
 <script src="/static/foo.10a400e06df8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I am still seeing

```
<script src="/static/foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Did I missed anything? In my settings, I do have 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `DEBUG` set to `True`? The staticfiles app only generates versioned URLs when debug mode is disabled.